# Ignore error messages when running a batch file but not in the typical way

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, batch-file, command, batch-processing

I know that there are ways to say
     IF ERRORMESSAGE GOTO 
but I've always seen these as simply telling the computer to move past a command that didn't work and go to the next one.

I have a batch file that will run about 30 files in a folder (simulations) to dump data into databases using sqlcmd. A lot of these files are older and might have compatibility issues. Usually I've got it running so that I can see it when an error message pops up and I can close it out so it can keep chugging on. However, it would be nice if I could have it running overnight and be finished by the morning whithout getting snagged on the error messages. I'll see the errors in the missing data so it doesn't matter.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
RMDIR c:\batchfolder /s /q
mkdir c:\batchfolder
xcopy "\\path\*" c:\batchfolder /s /i
cd c:\path\testfolder
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od') do set newest=%%a
cd c:\batchfolder
sqlcmd -S server -i "\\path\DropDatabases.sql"
for /D /r %%F IN ("*") DO ( 
   for %%G  IN ("%%F\*.extension") DO xcopy "%%G" c:\path\testfolder\%newest% /y /i
   for /f "delims=_" %%J IN ('forfiles /p "%%F" /m *.programext /c "cmd /c echo @path"')  DO start "PROGRAM"  /D "c:\path\testfolder" /Wait PROGRAM -r  %%J
)
sqlcmd -S MSA-SQL -i "\\path\dumpdataquery.sql"

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exit /b` to continue a loop when an error occurs. I assume the error happens when running "PROGRAM". To get around it, you can make the following change to the `for /f "delims=_" %%J` command.

```
    for /D /r %%F IN ("*") DO ( 
       for %%G  IN ("%%F\*.extension") DO xcopy "%%G" c:\path\testfolder\%newest% /y /i
       for /f "delims=_" %%J IN ('forfiles /p "%%F" /m *.programext /c "cmd /c echo @path"')  DO (
                start "PROGRAM"  /D "c:\path\testfolder" /Wait PROGRAM -r  %%J
                if not %errorlevel%==0 echo Error file %%F &&exit /b
        )
     )
```

Comment: I implemented that change but it didn't keep the error messages from freezing the batch script until I clicked okay

Comment: Many ?s: Is it PROGRAM that raises the error? If yes, it apparently doesn't raise an error code. Do you ever see "Error file %%F"? What is the error? Could it be in `sqlmcd`? (Also--prob unrelated--but please test changing `start "PROGRAM"` to `start "" "PROGRAM"`)

Comment: I will test that thank you. It is the program that is raising the errors. The errors (at least currently) are only for the program doing its thing but the sqlcmd line sare working beautifully. The error messages are various errors specific to the software.

Comment: Now realize the prompt on error in PROGRAM--for you to click ok--is the problem. With OK you reset the error code so it's always 0 (success) when it gets to the `if %errorlevel%` command. There's no way for a .bat file to send a keystroke to click ok. Could PROGRAM be modified? You said you see errors in missing data, so don't really need the prompt, right? Sorry, but now can't see any way errorlevel will work.